# How to render data that get from realm.objects

Tags: react-native, realm, flatlist

I'm using realm database for my react native applciation. I can able to create data into the realm database

```
 const createANewCategory = ( categoryName ) => {
        Realm.open( {
            path: 'myrealm.realm',
            schema: [CategorySchema],
        } ).then( ( realm ) => {
            realm.write( () => {
                const result = realm.create( 'Category', {
                    id: Math.random().toString( 36 ).substring( 7 ),
                    category_name: categoryName
                } );
                console.log( "New category created", result );
            } );
        } );
        setshowModal( false );
    };
```

Fetched the data from realm database to render in flatlist

```
    const [categories, setcategories] = useState( [] );

 useEffect( () => {
        Realm.open( {
            path: 'myrealm.realm',
            schema: [CategorySchema],
        } ).then( ( realm ) => {
            const categories = realm.objects( 'Category' );
            getArrayFromObject( categories );
            setcategories( categories );
        } );
    }, [] );
```

When I rendered data in flatlist, no data was rendered

```
    <FlatList
             data={ categories }
             keyExtractor={ ( item ) => item.id }
             renderItem={ itemData =>
             <CategoryCard
                 onPress={ navigateToAllDocuments }
                 title={ itemData.item }
              />
              }
     />
```

So the `categories` type returns **object** but it is array. That's why the `categories` not rendering in flatlist. Is there anyway to render data in flatlist